# How Can I remove element i selected from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
// Added during edit. This was not in OP's original code
var estate = [];

$("#select-estate").change(function() {
  var singleValues = $("#select-estate").val();
  if (estate.includes(singleValues) == false) {
    estate.push(singleValues);
    $("span.filter-push-select").append('<label class="active">' + singleValues + '<i class="fa fa-times fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>');
    $("span.filter-push-select label").click(function() {
      console.log(singleValues);
      console.log(estate);
      $(this).remove();
      estate.splice($("#select-estate").val(), 1);
      console.log(estate);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="increase" class="form-control" id="select-estate">
  <option disabled selected value="Select">Estate Type</option>
  <option value="ownership">ownership</option>
  <option value="rent">Rent</option>
</select>
<span class="filter-push-select"></span>
```

I use estate array and pull a value from select value html to append it and click to remove what I need. this function not true in removing from array and UI Append

Comment: Please post your html

Comment: I Post It in Answer

Comment: @MohamedSamy few things. First, please remove that answer(*thoug I do not have any privilege to ask you to do this, its a bad practice and will attract lot of unwanted attention*). Its abusing the ability. Second, please explain the expected behavior. What is happening and what should happen. Preferrably with example. Like *when A is selected, something should do something and when you do something else, say select B, what should happen*

Answer (score 0):

Check solution you were trying to check include on array I have added to string for check

```js
var estate=[];
$("#select-estate").change(function() {
  var singleValues = $("#select-estate").val();
  if (estate.toString().includes(singleValues) == false) {
    estate.push(singleValues);
    $("span.filter-push-select").append('<label class="active" style="cursor:pointer">' + singleValues + '<i class="fa fa-times fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></label><br/>');
    $("span.filter-push-select label").click(function() {
      console.log(singleValues);
      console.log(estate);
      $(this).remove();
      estate.splice($("#select-estate").val(), 1);
      console.log(estate);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="increase" class="form-control" id="select-estate">
       <option disabled selected value="Select">Estate Type</option>
       <option value="ownership">ownership</option>
       <option value="rent">Rent</option>
</select>
<br/>
<div>
<span class="filter-push-select"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: when delete rent value a ownership value is deleted and remain rain which should delete

Comment: after select value and click on it which selected such as ( rent), Output need to be: 
rent
[
  "ownership",
  "rent"
]
[
  "ownership"
]

Comment: and when click on ownership after selected it output :

ownership
[
  "ownership",
  "rent"
]
[
  "rent"
]